# What is the most modern way of stubbing/mocking a method in a Rails controller using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I've been using the technique described [in this article](http://johnnyji.me/rspec/2015/06/18/stubbing-controller-instance-methods-in-rspec.html) for mocking methods in controllers in my request specs.  TLDR, the technique uses "allow_any_instance_of" to mock controller methods. I've found some other StackOverflow posts which seem to agree with the article.

However, while reading through the [rspec 3.8 documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance), it says the following:

> - The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example, in expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear whether a specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)
> - Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex.
> - It is the most complicated feature of rspec-mocks, and has historically received the most bug reports. (None of the core team actively use it, which doesn't help.)

What is the correct and "modern" way to mock a method in a request spec?

I don't think the following matters, but just in case:

- Rails 5.2
- Ruby 2.4.1
- RSpec 3.8

Edit:  Adding some example code.

```
module A
  def my_pain
    puts "I don't want to run this during testing"
  end
end

class TestController < ApplicationController
  include A
  def index
    my_pain
  end
end
```

So what is the modern way to test "#index" while mocking "#my_pain" with RSpec in a controller/request test.

Comment: Regarding your comment on the 1st answer (contact other services): have you looked at using vcr/webmock for making (initially), saving, and then faking/replaying the response? You can make the request once, modify the yml file (to remove secrets or something if you needed to genericize it) and it will replay without making any future connections to the remote

Comment: If you can provide a specific example, I can show you how I would test it.

Comment: @JayDorsey I have not looked at vcr/webmock.  I will take a look at those.  From your description, it sounds promising.  However, while that might solve the case I'm concerned with right now, I was asking the question in a more general context.

Comment: @aridlehoover Hopefully the formatting displays correctly:

    module A
       def my_pain
          puts "I don't want to run this in testing"
       end
    end
    
    class TestController < ApplicationController
       include A
    
       def index
          my_pain
       end
    end

So write a controller/request test for "#index" in RSpec that mocks  "#my_pain".

Comment: @aridlehoover Obviously my trying to put a code example in the comments didn't work out at all.  I edited the original post with an example.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, we don't need to test the Controller, just take feature tests.
because what end-users are expecting is what will be rendered, not just navigation.

Comment: When I said controller methods, the methods I really want to mock are from helpers that are mixed-in to the controller which contact other services.  Those methods retrieve data that is used in rendering, calculations, etc. so I need them to return some fake data during testing.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach - try to mock as little as possible.

- Mock nothing until tests become slow or require external resources to configure.
  Then mock only dependencies/classes which are slow or access external
  resources(webservice, file system etc.)
- Mock nothing until test setup become very complicated.
  Then mock dependencies which contains very complicated logic, to simplify/reduce amount of logical branches to test.

In case you decided to mock some of dependencies:
If instance of dependency provided to the class under the test

```
class Order
    def initialize(printer)
        @printer = printer
    end

    def print
        @printer.print("my-printer", self)
    end
end

# Test
RSpec.describe "Order.print" do
    it "prints order to my printer" do
        fake_printer = double("Printer", :print => nil)
        order = Order.new(fake_printer)

        expect(fake_printer).to receive(:print).with("my-printer", order)

        order.print
    end
end
```

If instance of dependency instantiated inside class under the test

```
class Order
    def initialize
        @printer = Printer.new("my-printer")
    end

    def print
        @printer.print(self)
    end
end

# Test
RSpec.describe "Order.print" do
    it "prints order to my printer" do
        fake_printer = double("Printer", :print => nil)
        allow(Printer).to receive(:new).with("my-printer").and_return(fake_printer)

        order = Order.new

        expect(fake_printer).to receive(:print).with(order)

        order.print
    end
end
```

Notice that when you are using `double("ClassName")` you need to configure all methods which will be called during the test, if not - exception will be thrown.

[RSpec Test Doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs)

Comment: OP asked for modern way of mocking a method in a controller spec.